# How to list breakpoints in radare2?

Tags: radare2, breakpoint

in gdb to list active breakpoints is `info b` how to do the same in radare2? is there any similar command in radare2 or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db` is used both to set a breakpoint and to list all breakpoints. As you can be see in the command's help output:

```
[0x00007f60]> db?
|Usage: db  # Breakpoints commands
| db                       List breakpoints
| db sym.main              Add breakpoint into sym.main
| db <addr>                Add breakpoint
| db -<addr>               Remove breakpoint
| db.                      Show breakpoint info in current offset
| dbj                      List breakpoints in JSON format
| dbc <addr> <cmd>         Run command when breakpoint is hit
| dbC <addr> <cmd>         Set breakpoint condition on command
| dbd <addr>               Disable breakpoint
...
...
```

So simply do something like this:

```
$ r2 -d /bin/cat

Process with PID 261 started...
= attach 261 261
bin.baddr 0x00400000
Using 0x400000
asm.bits 64
 -- Hang in there, Baby!

[0x7f5399600c30]> db entry0
[0x7f5399600c30]> db main
[0x7f5399600c30]> db
0x004025b0 - 0x004025b1 1 --x sw break enabled cmd="" cond="" name="entry0" module="/bin/cat"
0x004019e0 - 0x004019e1 1 --x sw break enabled cmd="" cond="" name="main" module="/bin/cat"
[0x7f5399600c30]>
```